# Dropwizard - override the url for the healthcheck endpoint

Tags: servlets, jetty, dropwizard

Dropwizard uses the Codahale Metrics HealthCheck servlet. When using the servlet outside of dropwizard you can override the URI by setting the init-param "healthcheck-uri".

Is there a way to override it in dropwizard?

It looks like it would be something to do with setting an init-param on the NonblockingServletHolder.

Comment: Are you still having an issue?

Answer (score 0):

You are right that a NonblockingServletHolder is being constructed. The issue is that the Dropwizard DefaultServerFactory isn't transferring any of the params set in the applicationContext or adminContext, which are both a part of the dropwizard Environment.

I believe your only viable option is to extend the AbstractServerFactory and set the init params in the config for the AdminServlet before it is initialized. The DefaultServerFactory can be extended and set by your Configuration child class.

```
class MyServerFactory extends DefaultServerFactory{
        //Copied from AbstractServerFactory
        protected Handler createAdminServlet(Server server,
                                             MutableServletContextHandler handler,
                                             MetricRegistry metrics,
                                             HealthCheckRegistry healthChecks) {
            //Copied from AbstractServerFactory.configureSessionsAndSecurity because its private and can't be called here
            if (handler.isSecurityEnabled()) {
                handler.getSecurityHandler().setServer(server);
            }
            if (handler.isSessionsEnabled()) {
                handler.getSessionHandler().setServer(server);
            }
            handler.setServer(server);
            handler.getServletContext().setAttribute(MetricsServlet.METRICS_REGISTRY, metrics);
            handler.getServletContext().setAttribute(HealthCheckServlet.HEALTH_CHECK_REGISTRY, healthChecks);
            //HERE - set the init parameter and add the servlet
            def holder = new NonblockingServletHolder(new AdminServlet())
            holder.setInitParameter("healthcheck-uri", "/myurl")
            handler.addServlet(holder, "/*");
            //END

            handler.addFilter(AllowedMethodsFilter.class, "/*", EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST))
                    .setInitParameter(AllowedMethodsFilter.ALLOWED_METHODS_PARAM, Joiner.on(',').join(allowedMethods));
            return handler;
        }
    }
```

Configuration child class:

```
class MyConfiguration extends Configuration{

  MyConfiguration(){
    setServerFactory(new MyServerFactory())
  }
}
```

**For what its worth**:

I dove into the code that initializes the servlets and realized after a while that I couldn't do anything without overriding what the ServerFactory is doing:
The dropwizard Environment has an adminContext, applicationContext and ServletEnvironment all of which allow you to set initialization parameters. The AdminServlet class is the place where the init param of "healthcheck-uri" is used, so I was hopeful that setting these parameters in the adminContext would pass them through to the AdminServlet, but alas, they are not because the Jetty ServletContextHandler that ultimately sets up the AdminServlet has the init params buried in _servletHandler._servletContext._initParams.

**None of these do anything for you**:

```
    environment.adminContext.setInitParameter("healthcheck-uri","/something")
    environment.applicationContext.setInitParameter("healthcheck-uri","/something")
    environment.servlets().setInitParameter("healthcheck-uri","/something")
    environment.admin().setInitParameter("healthcheck-uri","/something")
```